# Javascript onclick event doesn´t fire

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, onclick

I have some code here:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function () 
    {
        var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
        document.href("http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm);
    }
</script>
<body>
<center>
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
    <input type="text" name="q"> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="startSearch()">
</center>
```

which does not work. I know this is such a noob stuff at all, but I don´t know javascript. Can anyone help me please?

Addition:

I also tried:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
<input type="text" name="q"> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="startSearch()">
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function () 
{
    var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
    document.href = "http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm;
}
     };
```

and:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
<input type="text" name="q"> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Search" name="searchButton" onclick="startSearch()">
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
function triggerGoogleSearch() 
{
var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
document.href("http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm);
}   

document.getElementById('searchButton').onclick = triggerGoogleSearch();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have rolled back your question to the second revision. It seems that was the question you asked and got answered. Don't edit your questions into completely new ones. The answers received might no longer apply. Just ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: In this case the answers fitted to the modified question but you´re right, sorry

Comment: Hmm, the user who wrote the accepted answer modified your question [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12689017/4). I assume you see now how problematic this all is? Please don't do that again. Things will only end up in a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function ()
```

to this:

```
function startSearch ()
```

and change this:

```
document.href("http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm);
```

to this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm;
```

And also add `id="bereich"` to your `<input type="text" name="q">` like this:

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="bereich">
```

if you want to find it by getElementById.

Also, change the url from:

```
http://www.google.com/serach
```

to this:

```
http://www.google.com/search
```

## UPDATE:

Actually never mind all of those corrections and **forget about JavaScript!**

Just make a simple HTML form:

```
<img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

See [**THIS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDuhn/).

I think that we were all trying to fix your code and completely missed a much simpler solution. :)

Comment: can you stick it to a complete code because I don´t know what´s the initial code for the changes... I tried every answer and every edit of every answer, nothing is working...

Comment: @Paedow see my updated answer with a working demo

Comment: ok, this is perfect... but I still wonder why none of the javascript versions worked... by the way: I use Firefox 18.0.1a Build 20121001030603. Could it be that the browser just crashes the script?

Comment: @Paedow there were many small mistakes in your code, most of them I thing were corrected by me and others here but one thing that everyone missed is that **it is `window.location.href` and not `document.href`!** Your JavaScript version (after corrections) may work if you add this one change.

Comment: oh thats really scumbag mistake :)

Comment: @rsp the problem is that the question we have now isn't at all what we have initially. We didn't miss something : the question was about an event not fired.

Comment: @dystroy what I was saying is that we missed the `document.href` in the original question and no one has changed it to `window.location.href` or `window.location` in their corrections.

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* errors in this code. I list a few of them but I may have missed some.

1) Put your script at the end of the body and it will work. Now it is executed before the element exist. So the event handler isn't added at all.

2) there is no `document.href` function. Use `document.href =`

3) you don't have any element with id myElement or bereich

4) you need to encode the search term

5) it's probably "search", not "serach"

6) your button does nothing it calls a non-existing function

7) And it's better to enclose it in an onload callback :

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
    <input type="text" name="q" id=bereich> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Search" id=myElement">
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function () 
    {
        var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
        document.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(searchterm);
    }
         };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried it right now, doesn´t work...

Comment: I fixed some other errors. Still looking for more.

Comment: But you do you have a button that you don't use ?

Comment: no thie code above is the only code for my site

Comment: The button isn´t unused... there is a image, a text box and a button, when the button is clicked i want the browser to search the text of the textbox at google...

Comment: I think that this code may work if you change `document.href` to `window.location.href` or `window.location` but still I think that using JavaScript to emulate a model use case of a simple `<form>` element is an overkill (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689017/javascript-onclick-event-doesnt-fire/12689108#12689108) and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JDuhn/)). But still +1 for good explanation of almost all the mistakes.

Comment: @rsp I agree it's overkill. But that was the initial question. Now the question is so different it should be closed...

Comment: I think that the original question should be restored. Meanwhile I added a link to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function triggerGoogleSearch() 
{
    var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
    document.href("http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm);
}   

document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = triggerGoogleSearch();
```

Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><br>
    <input type="text" name="q"> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="startSearch()" id="myElement">
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function () 
    {
        var searchterm = document.getElementById('bereich').value;
        document.href("http://www.google.com/serach?q=" + searchterm);
    }
         };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```